# How to use quantlib with excel?

Tags: quantlib

I installed an quantlib on my mac, but have no idea, how to start using it with an excel. Please advise hoq to do it. I followed all instructions here:
http://quantlib.org/install/macosx.shtml. I think I need a kind of add-in or so.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help, looks i need new comp with Windows :)
Cheers,
Michal

Answer (score 8):

The QuantLib you installed is just a C++ library.

If you were on a Windows machine, you'd need the QuantLibXL addin to use it in Excel (http://quantlib.org/quantlibxl/).  But on a Mac, you've no such luck.  As far as I know, Excel for Mac only allows addins written in VBA, so QuantLibXL can't be built for it.

Answer (score 1):

Deriscope is also an Excel addin that exposes almost all QuantLib pricing routines to Excel.